# Determine whether $ (A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4)$ span $M_{22}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine whether $\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&1\\1&-1\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right], \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]$ spans $M_{22}$. If it does, construct the set of basis from the spanning set.

Pick an arbitrary matrix in $M_{22}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\z&w\end{array}\right]$.If we find the following system to be consistent, then this set will span $M_{22}$

$a_1\left[\begin{array}{cc}-1&1\\1&-1\end{array}\right]+ a_2\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right]+a_3 \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1&0\\0&1\end{array}\right]+a_4\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&1\\1&0\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}x&y\\z&w\end{array}\right]$ which simplifies to

$$-a_1+a_2+a_3=x$$
$$a_1+a_2+a_4=y$$
$$a_1+a_2+a_4=z$$
$$-a_1+a_2+a_3=w$$
By visually inspecting, we can see that eq #1 & 4 are the same and eq#2 & 3 are the same. So, if we perform row operations, we will end up with an inconsistent system. So, the set do no span $M_{22}$ and we cannot construct the basis.

Am  I on the right track? Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: It’s enough to note that the space of matrices is four dimensional and the four matrices that you list at the start are linearly dependent. The second matrix is the sum of the third and fourth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if the set doesn't span $M_{22}$, it span some subspace $\subseteq M_{22}$; we need to find the basis for such subspace.

To find it you can proceed as for ordinary row/colum vectors by RREF (in this way you could solve also part 1 by this) and selecting matrices corresponding to the pivot rows.

Notably, collecting the matrices by rows with the entries ordered as for $x,y,z,w$, we have to reduce the following

$$\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&1&-1\\1&1&1&1\\1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&0 \end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&1&-1\\1&1&1&1\\0&-1&-1&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&1&-1\\0&2&2&0\\0&-1&-1&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}-1&1&1&-1\\0&2&2&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

from here we can conlude that the subspace spanned has dimension 2 and that we can take the first two matrices as a basis for it.

Comment: Why not just discard the first and second matrices which are clearly in the span of the third and fourth?

Comment: @BRT of course in special cases we can find many shorcuts but I prefer Always to give a view for more general methods

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and short cut method. Both helps me figure out how to tackle this kind of problems. As for the set spanning some subset contained in $M_{22}$, can I say that the set spans some subspace of $M_{22}$ for which the system of equation is consistent? This system of equation will be consistent when certain constraints for x,y,z and w are met.

Comment: Yes of course, the system $Ax=b$ has solutions for vectors b in this subspace. If A contains only the basis, x is unique otherwise we have infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the dimension of the space is 4 and if $A_1,...,A_4$ are the matrices in the question we have $A_2 = A_3+A_4$, hence the dimension of the span of the $A_k$
can be no more than 3.

Here is another approach:
Let $L$ be the linear functional that adds the top row and subtracts the bottom row. We see that $L (A_k) = 0$ for all $A_k$, but $L$ is not the zero operator, hence the $A_k$ cannot span the entire space. That is, $\ker L$ is not the entire space.

We also observe that $A_1 = A_4-A_3$, hence the span has dimension of at most 2 and since $A_3,A_4$ do not lie on a line we see that the span has dimension 2.

So, we need to find two linearly independent matrices that do not lie in $\operatorname{sp}\{ A_3,A_4\}$. We see that $A \in \operatorname{sp}\{ A_3,A_4\}$ **iff** $[A]_{11} = [A]_{22}$ and $[A]_{12}=[A]_{21}$.

A straightforward selection would be $E_{11}, E_{12}$ (where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix of zeros except for a one in the ${ij}$ position).